# Use of mflo statement

Tags: assembly, mips

When,where and why should the mflo statement be used in assembly language?

Comment: I have tagged your question, which may completely change its meaning, but if it does, that means the question was particularly meaningless without the tag.

Answer (score 1):

By extrapolation from [this document](http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/mips%20quick%20tutorial.htm), when you want to access the result of a multiplication or division on a MIPS processor.

Answer (score 1):

MIPS multiplier is a separate unit, and instructions within the unit consume more than other integer instructions. This is why there is a different handling of this unit and results it provides.

Usage of this unit is as follows:

1. start multiply of divide
2. execute the instructions in parallel
3. store results in register `HI` and `LO`, when finished
4. read results with `mfhi` and `mflo`

Note that if results are not ready when you try to read them, the CPU will wait until they arrive.

If you decide to use `mul` and `div` instructions, you do not need to think about `mfhi` and `mflo` instructions.